# Opendaylight feature installation "No matching features for odl-dlux-core/0.0.0" error

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to install feature:install odl-dlux-all but getting below error,

> Error executing command: No matching features for odl-dlux-all/0.0.0

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is Fluorine - dlux was eliminated from the release due to inactivity and no longer being maintained by anyone. If you're interested, the ODL community would welcome any contributions to reboot and maintain the project.

Comment: Thanks Tom, Yes, this is in Fluorine. 
I am exploring ODL. If the dlux has been discontinued, probably I'll use Carbon or Oxygen. Should be a way to onboard dlux feature in Fluorine, any links to refer please suggest.